# MASShortcut - default value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way to set initial shortcut for MASShortcut when there is no shortcut recorded? Or on first launch?

Something like:

```
[MASShortcut setDefaultShortcut: ....];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

Either you can work around it by creating a temp during startup and validating it:

```
MASShortcutView *tempView = [[MASShortcutView alloc] init];
[tempView setAssociatedUserDefaultsKey:key];
MASShortcut *shortcutVal = tempView.shortcutValue;
if (shortcutVal && shortcutVal.keyCodeStringForKeyEquivalent) {
    // Shortcut exists
} else {
    // Assign default shortcut here
}
```

Or do it as the author suggests [here](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut/issues/18).